# How can I maintain interest with a repeating bassline?

Tags: composition

If it helps, this is my bassline(opening the piece as the melody of a chorale), for a classical orchestra plus trombones and piano.
[image: Bassline]

This bassline has to repeat for the entirety of the piece, with the possible exception of a coda. I've composed 6 variations at this point, and the repetition is notable. How does one mask the repetition? Brahms does this in the finale of his last symphony to great effect, but I have some difficulty analyzing his techniques and I find it exhausting to analyze orchestra scores. The harmony is limited, but I can still use rhythmic, melodic, and textural variation. Are there any concrete techniques to this form to mask the repetition?

Comment: Pachelbel's Canon in D repeats its baseline throughout, yet is immensely popular.

Comment: @It'sHEDLEY Firstly, that piece is much shorter(with less variations) than I intend mine to be. Secondly, do you know how many people are driven insane by Canon in D?

Comment: Imagine soloing on a repeated bassline and you should get some ideas. Feel free to **reharmonize** some variations.

Answer (score 1):

The object of some of this sort of writing **is** to keep *something* going all through, as, for example, the snare in Bolero. It's the constant against the rest of the piece changing. Ostinato.

But - if you want it to change but stay the same, various options are available.

Alter the length of each note - even down to staccato.

Change the volume of each note, either playing pp, ff, or cresc., - decresc. for a couple of 'verses'.

Double up so each note is half as long, but played twice. Or thrice in 3/4 time.

Play the note so it starts a quaver early, sort of shifting the beat sooner.

Delaying the note, so there's a quaver rest before it's played.

Play two instead of one - note, octave above, note, in each bar.

Move that eight bar motif around to other instruments - a really nice idea, used many times already, kind of 'trading eights', or 'passing the baton'(sic).

By using these in combination, there are many, many variations available!

Comment: I'm trying to keep something all the way through without making it boring. A lot of pieces like that, even by great composers(like Bolero, or Canon in D), get some hammering at for being repetitive and boring. But, my previously mentioned Brahms movement lasts more than 9 minutes, and is anything but boring. Bach's Goldberg Variations, and his famous Chaconne in Dm, follow the same formula, and you get (REDACTED) by the Bach police if you call either of them boring, or so much as say anything about them that isn't superlative-filled praise. What did Bach and Brahms do that Ravel and...

Comment: ...Pachelbel didn't? This is my first piece that actually has a(low, but non-zero) chance of being performed, and killing the audience with boredom isn't a good move for a first premiere.

Comment: Another idea is to arrange your variations in increasing order of complexity (and hopefully interest). You can also (if allowed by the terms of the composition) change the harmony but keep the bass note the same.

Answer (score 0):

Brahms does in fact **not** just keep repeating the Bass line in the fourth movement of his fourth symphony. You might want to check out ciaconnas and passacaglias that keep to the bass line more strictly, e.g. Bach’s organ passacaglia in c minor.

You have a handful of options to vary the bass itself. You can change the rhythm, the dynamics, the orchestration, you might even feature the line in a different orchestral voice. But the rest has to come from the other voices. Even though the bass is the same you want to avoid a feeling of uniformity and repetition. You want to evoke different characters, different harmonic interpretations of the same bass line, different rhythmic interpretations and such. **This means that optimally you’d compose your base line in such a way that you can do these things!** So optimally you’d want your baseline to allow for lots of **interesting** harmonic progressions.

Really importantly the rest of your voices should be interesting enough to distract from the repeated bass line. But also the bass line should be something that is interesting enough to warrant hearing it more than once. If your bass line is boring on the third time you hear it isolated, it will probably not be well suited for basing a whole piece on the repetition of it.

Again, if you want to learn about these kind of things, you’d best study pieces where this is a principal design choice by composer who really had experience doing this, so baroque and renaissance ciaconnas and passacaglias.

Comment: I've heard from several sources that the Brahms movement IS a Chaconne/Passacaglia. Namely these: https://houstonsymphony.org/brahms-symphony-4/  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PxyyVVphogo      https://archive.schillerinstitute.com/fid_97-01/984_sub_moral_appen_PDFs/chapter8.PDF

Comment: The first six variations are pretty bare-boned, maybe that was my problem. I was more attempting a Beethoven style-variation, where each variation gets progressively more complex.

Comment: @OprenStein Yes, the last movement of Brahms 4th **is** considered a ciaconna or a passacaglia by some. It is definitely composed as a variation movement, and it has quite a few variations that feature the theme in the bass. But still Brahms is not strictly sticking to this theme, especially in the middle variations.

Comment: Look at the Brahms, the Pachelbel.  The bass lines aren't interesting, but they're STRONG.

Comment: @Laurence Well, you can call it that if you want.